# MySql - Table 'proc' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql

My app consists of a function in which I'm trying to lock a table, update it (using a stored procedure) and then unlock it. The code goes something like:

```
LOCK TABLE mytable WRITE;
CALL myStoredProc;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

When the function is called, it errors out when the `CALL myStoredProc;` part is executed giving the following error message:

```
Table 'proc' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

I tried locking `mysql.proc` along with `mytable` but that didn't seem to help. Any ideas on this type of scenario?

**Update:**
The first stored procedure goes as follows:

```
CALL mystoredproc2(NOW());
UPDATE mytable SET _column = NOW();
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE _column > NOW();
```

As you see, the above stored procedure nests another one. The second one simply contains an update statement:

```
UPDATE mytable2 SET _column = _now;
```

FYI: I've also locked `mytable2` in the lock statement but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `proc` != `mytable`: perhaps show [relevant parts in] `magicalStoredProc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the nested `mystoredproc2` stored procedure outside the `mystoredproc` as a series of SQL statements and that did the trick.